# Multiple Image animation

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have two images one of usb cable and another of connecter, I want to make a animation where the cable moves into the connector, and the part inside the connector fades away

Basic image attached http://code.webplatform.org/gist/7715993

Comment: @codehorse I am not asking you to do it for me.. I asking for some directions.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways figured it out myself... had an idea of moving the usb along some curved path.. lots of work.. so instead i used transform x y to move the usb to socket in a slope path..